# Can anyone explain to me how this script works?

Tags: bash, find, tr

I was looking for a script that changes the filename and directory name to lowercase and replaces any white spaces with "-". I managed to find the script below inside another script but I do not fully understand how it works. I would really appreciate it if someone could walk me through it.

```
find ./* -depth -type d -exec sh -c '
t=${0%/*}/$(printf %s "${0##*/}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]");
[ "$t" = "$0" ] || mv -i "$0" "$t"
' {} \;
```

Comment: Which bits **do** you understand?

Comment: I understand "find ./* -depth -type d" and "tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find ./* -depth -type d -exec sh -c ' ... ' {} \;
```

`find`s all directories (`-type d`) in the tree and runs that shell snippet for each of them, with `$0` set to the current name. `-depth` makes it process the contents of each directory first, and the directory itself last. (otherwise the renaming messes things up.)

```
t=${0%/*}/$(printf %s "${0##*/}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]");
```

`${0%/*}` removes the last slash and everything after it from `$0`, i.e. leaves the directory name. `${0##*/}` is basically the opposite. (They're types of [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)) The `printf | tr` is used to change the final part of the name to lower case. The result is assigned to `t`. (`$(...)` is [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution))

```
[ "$t" = "$0" ] || mv -i "$0" "$t"
```

[Tests](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) to see if the new name in `t` and the old name in `$0` are the same, and if *not*, then calls `mv` on them.

---

The silly parts here are that `find` could be called just as `find . -depth ...`, there's no need for the filename wildcard (`find ./*`) since finding the file names is what `find` does. If they used `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, there would be no need to deal with the directory part of the file names. And using `$0` for the target file name is a bit bad form, it's meant for the name of the script itself.

---

You mentioned renaming files and directories, and changing whitespace to dashes. As far as I can see, the command here does neither. `find -type d` only catches directories, you'd need to use `-type f` to catch only regular files, or leave it out to ignore the type. Also, there's nothing about whitespace in the `tr`, but you could change it to, say `tr "[:upper:][:space:]" "[:lower:][-*]"` to also change all whitespace to dashes.

Comment: @steeldriver, ah, true, I'd already forgotten that when I reached the end...

Answer (score 0):

I would use larry walls `rename`, it is available on many distros. Including Debian, and probably derivatives.

```
rename -E 's/-//g' -E 's/(.*)/\L$1/g' *
```

First expression **s**earch and replaces `-` with nothing. second expression search and replaces everything `(.*)` with the same thing `$1` but converted to lowercase `\L`

Comment: The main problem with `rename` is it's inconsistent. The default `rename` is different between debian and red hat variants, and even Debian has multiple providers for `/usr/bin/rename`.

Comment: ... and is not recursive ... plus I was looking for an explanation not a different method. Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The script you present does some things to extract the directory and changes it to lowercase. There is no change of `white space` to `-`.

To change space to - and lowercase the string, sed works fine:

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/-/g' -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'
```

So, this script should work:

```
find ./* -depth -type d -execdir sh -c '
t=$(printf %s "${1}" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/-/g' -e "s/\(.*\)/\L\1/")
[ "$t" = "$1" ] || echo mv -i "$1" "$t"
' sh {} \;
```

Using `-depth` and `-execdir` avoids the need to extract the dir name.
The `type d` limits the selected elements to only directories.